# Aks SecretProviderClass secret not found

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

EDIT: Found the issue.I didnt installed the addon for secret driver. Once installed that i was able to make it work

I am facing an issue here and i have no idea what else i can try to figure out the issue.

I have an aks running with a single pod that runs a basic web app `todo list`. Nothing too fancy or complicated. what i am trying to do here, is to give permission to the aks cluster to access a keyvault and `GET` a secret to pass to the pod. the secret is just an `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development`.

Following the documentations, i used helm to install the repo:

```
helm repo add csi-secrets-store-provider-azure https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/charts
helm install csi csi-secrets-store-provider-azure/csi-secrets-store-provider-azure
```

I created a Service Principle in azure:
`SERVICE_PRINCIPLE_CLIENT_SECRET = az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment --name sp-aks-keyvault`

i queried the clientId and Secret and passed them to my cluster as follow:

```
kubectl create secret generic secrets-store-creds --from-literal clientid="ClientID" --from-literal clientsecret="Password"
```

Once everything was set. I set those deployments.

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapp
          image: dockerimage-acr
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: aspenet-environment
                key: environment
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          volumeMounts:
          - name: secrets-mount
            mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
            readOnly: true
      restartPolicy: Always 
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-mount
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "kv-name"
            nodePublishSecretRef:                       # Only required when using service principal mode
              name: secrets-store-creds
```

And my secretProvider.yaml

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: keyvault-secret-class
  namespace: default
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: aspenet-environment
      type: Opaque
      data:
      - objectName: aspnetcoreenvironment
        key: environment
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "false"
    userAssignedIdentityID: ""
    keyvaultName: "mykeyvault-name"
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: aspnetcoreenvironment
          objectType: secret
          objectVersion: ""
    tenantId: "<Tenant-Id>"
```

In my keyvault i gave access policy to the Service principle created and assigned `Secret Permissions: GET` and created a secret called

```
Name: aspnetcoreenvironment
value: Development
```

So far everything went ok, but when i run the deployment. and use the command `kubectl describe pod <podname>` i see the error, that prevents the container to start

```
Warning  Failed     8s (x3 over 21s)  kubelet            Error: secret "aspenet-environment" not found
```

I tried different solutions but nothing works.
if i run the command `kubectl get secretproviderclass` i get back my provider i created.
As far as i understand, if no service is requiring a specific secret, i wont be able to find the secret i want to create if i run the command: `kubectl get secret`

And this is correct, i guess, because my pod is not starting.

Any help or enlightenment here about what i am doing wrong or how to fix it?

Thank you so much guys

EDIT:
Some extra debugging i came across the fact that the volume mount is still required. So i did add the volume to the deployment. But this is still giving an error.

The issue is, as i realized. Is when i run the command `kubectl apply -f secretProviderClass.yml`, no secret get created at all, reason why is failing.
So i think something is wrong here. Applying the SecretProviderClass shouldnt create automatically a `secret` service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The creation of SecretProviderClass object does not automatically create the secret within kubernetes. The `secret` object gets created only when there is an actual pod running within the cluster which is utilising the defined **SecretProviderClass**.

This behaviour is documented under:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver

**Sync mounted content with a Kubernetes secret**

`You might want to create a Kubernetes secret to mirror your mounted secrets content. Your secrets will sync after you start a pod to mount them. When you delete the pods that consume the secrets, your Kubernetes secret will also be deleted.`